# How do I include common lines of code in a Python module where I am assigning a number of variables? (copycode)

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python. I am trying to modularize my program but I need each module to have common knowledge, re: displacement within my rows (file layout). I want to maintain flexibility.

Here is an example:

```
fdb_MemberNumbr = 1
fdb_FullName = 2
fdb_MemberLevel = 3
fdb_WP_User_ID = 16
fdb_Email = 18
fdb_ImageInfoList = 19
fdb_Aggregate_Score = 26
fdb_Number_Of_Entries = 36
fdb_Place = 38
fdb_TrophyWinner = 39
fdb_HighestImageScore = 40
```

I would like to be able to include a common code segment similar to the above in many of my modules, such that I can change it in one place and all of the modules will automatically include it at run time e.g., `%include fdb_copycode.py`

Comment: `%include` is a C preprocessor directive. It has no direct counterpart in Python. The nearest to an equivalent is `import` but it works differently because imported code is *executed at import time*. This may produce baffling results if you are expecting something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could define all these variables in a `constants.py` file, which you can import from another `.py` file using `import constants` (files should be in same directory). Your variables would be accessible like: `constants.fdb_MemberNumbr`. Note that there are many manners in which one can import modules.

Comment: I tested this approach by creating a module called cc with my file layout but I get the following error on the first line of code     images = mdbstructure[cc.fdb_ImageInfoList]
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fdb_ImageInfoList'

Comment: What you describe is another problem which is beyond your initial question. However, ```mdbstructure``` is a function (as you can decode from the error message), which has no attributes (variables stored within an object). You attempt to retrieve a variable within a function, but since the function does not contain that attribute (which it shouldn't as a function should have functionality to execute something, not be a placeholder for variables), the error you describe is shown.

Comment: Hi Mattias.  Thank you for answering my question.  If I have the following code where masterdic is a dictionary: 
mdbstructure = masterdic[memberno]       
images = mdbstructure[cc.fdb_ImageInfoList]
? why isn't mdbstructure a variable as opposed to a function?  Sorry this looks messy.  Perhaps there is a better way to attach code segments to a question?

Comment: I have played with this for a while and now I get it.  I was placing the constants in their own module.  They should be just straight constants with no def and no return.  I was able to get it to work.